# How to define global launch configuration in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have several projects that require the same custom launch configuration.

Instead of creating a `launch.json` in each project I would like to have a global `launch.json` so that it can be easily maintained.

Is there any way to achieve this in VSCode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a global launch configuration in your user settings.json file
Just add the launch json object there.
This is also documented:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/debugging.md#global-launch-configuration